# How to micro/counter siege tanks properly in TvT

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm wondering how to micro siege tanks in different modes. For example,

**1. When you are harassing another Terran with siege tanks**:

The best option is to avoid that and make a drop to undefended part, but if he brought own tanks under your expand and you need to protect expand?

In this case it would be good to bring you tanks till the 12-13 range of opponents tanks (they won't be able to shoot your while sight is not provided for them) and get sight from the own site... But this is often hard to do...

Another option would be good to have some banshees/BCs (if opponent doesn't have too much vikings). But if opponent has? use Ravens+SeekingMissiles?

Or push with stimmed marauders?
Thors?

What suites best for this case?

**2. Does it makes sense to play with tanks range?**

For example, opponent has 6-8 tanks in groups that are in few rows (1st row - 3 tanks, a little bit behind - 3 more tanks...) Is it reasonable to try to put your tanks in range but out of sight of opponent tanks?

This seems reasonable if you have air superiority, but requires a lot of micro... and actually is a little bit risky (he can scan you and kill easily while you tanks are not in siege mode yet).

If this seems reasonable, what is amount of tanks you need to bring to be successful with that?

**3. Can you make another example and solution for that?**

offense, defense, combat, drop, etc...

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks a lot

P.S. I'm interested in advises for Platinum/Diamond player level.

Comment: Plat and diamond? What, you don't want to hear from us master league players? :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need control of the air or a bunch more tanks than him to break it.  I find it useful to click on his tanks to see their range just before I move mine, so I can be sure to get as close as possible without taking damage.

Unless the tank numbers are very different between you and your opponent, usually the one who walks into the tank fire loses.  Whenever I see someone massing siege tanks, I immediately start thinking about what I can do to get him to unsiege and give up his position.

Things that have worked for me:

1. Nukes!  Drop a nuke, if he moves out just move in and siege up (ideally in range of a command center), otherwise let the nuke do it's work.  You'll probably have to get cloak for this to work.
2. Get a tech lab on the Starport.  Banshees and BC's are great when he's playing defensive with tanks.
3. Drop Marines or Marauders one by one in the middle of his tank ball.  Friendly fire is brutal.

Also remember that even though his tank line holds his position well, he's likely not defending all of his structures.  Peek around to see if you can blow up some supply depots or a risky expansion.

Also, I'm not Plat+ like you suggested, so consider the source :)

Comment: Thanks. Good ideas... Actually, one guy tried to do BC against my sieged tanks... I remember he was able to break my lines... but, probably he over-invested in BCs while I invested in mass vikings, so I get air back... But nukes - is a good way, agree...

Comment: Why drop marauders and not cheaper marines?

Comment: Marauders seem to get 2 friendly fire shots off, while marines only get 1.  I guess this depends on the number of tanks.

Comment: 2 marines are cheaper than 1 marauder